# Crystal reports /IIS error, after I moved WEB from IIS6 to IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, iis-6

I try to move WEB site from 32 bit Windows 2003 to 64 bit Windows 2008. Old server has CR for .net framework 2.0 (10.2.3600.0). I installed on new server CR for .net (13.0.2000.0) and all my reports do not work. IN VS 2012 I found next error:
Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'DisplayGroupTree' is not a valid attribute of element CrystalReportViewer'.
Web.config has next lines:
 
        
        
        
        
        
        
      
I have searched the net for a solution but haven't found any answers.

Please help

Thanks in advance
Vlad

Answer (score 0):

`.DisplayGroupTree`, as well as several other properties that I don't recall offhand, were removed in the .NET 4.0 version of the Crystal Viewer. Look for references to this property in your code behinds and/or designers and remove them.

That brings back fond memories.